# MTG: march of Multitudes and Early Harvest

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If cast [March of the Multitudes](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarch%20of%20the%20Multitudes%5d) and use most of my lands to pay the extra X amount can I cast [Early Harvest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEarly%20Harvest%5d) to use the lands again?

Comment: I am assuming you are asking about using the lands again to increase the value of X in March of Multitudes; as opposed to just using the lands again for something else this turn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you do things in the right order. While you are casting a spell and paying the cost, you don’t have priority to do something like cast Early Harvest, so you cannot do this if you start to cast March of the Multitudes first. By the time you would be able to cast Early Harvest, March of the Multitudes would be finished being cast and couldn’t be changed afterwards.

However, you can tap all your lands first, producing some amount of mana; then cast Early Harvest; then tap all your lands again. This will let you use all of your lands twice to have double your normal amount of mana (minus the 3 you spent on Early Harvest). All of this mana will stay until the end of the current step; so you can use it to cast March of the Multitudes.

Comment: @TheBeholder If this answered your question please use the check mark to mark it as the correct answer, thanks!